# Excel : Why do advanced filters erase values below the extracting zone when copy mode is used?

Tags: excel, advanced-filter

I hope StackOverflow is the right place to ask this, as this is not VBA.

I'm using an Advanced Filter to export some data from a small DB to an invoice.
I want to automate that export, and I figured the best way to do it (without VBA) would be to use an advanced filter.

It works well, but it erases all the text below the destination zone, in the invoice itself.
It's intended to be printed and sent to a client, so I need the greetings below.

Why is that ?
The copied data doesn't overlap with the greetings at all, they are a few lines below.

Thanks!